# Fundamental theorem of calculus left limit

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f(x)$ is integrable and $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$. How to show that if $f(x)$ has left limit at $x_0$ then $F'_{-}(x_0) = f(x_0^{-})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{F(x_0+h)-F(x_0)}{h}-f(x_0^-)\right|\leq \frac{1}{h}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}|f(t)-f(x_0^-)|dt.$$
Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f$ has a limit at $x_0^-$, there is $\tilde h>0$ small enough s.t. $$|f(t)-f(x_0^-)|<\varepsilon,$$
for all $t\in ]x_0-\tilde h,x_0[.$
In particular, if $0<h<\tilde h$, $$\frac{1}{h}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}|f(t)-f(x_0^-)|dt\leq \varepsilon.$$
The claim follow.

Comment: How did you get the equation on the first line?

Comment: @sedrick : $f(x_0^-)=\frac{1}{h}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(x_0^-)dt.$

Comment: Wait, sorry, why is that true? Is $h$ approaching zero, or is this true for any $h$?

Comment: @sedrick $\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(x_0^-)dt=f(x_0^-)\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}dt=f(x_0^-)(x_0+h-x_0)=hf(x_0^-)$, so it is true for any $h$.